# How to make a component to full screen in ngx-admin Template?

Tags: typescript, angular8

I have been trying to make my new login page component to the full screen in the ngx-admin template. Whenever I try to show the login component it comes inside to template with a side nav. I created this login component inside the pages module. Please help me to convert it to full-screen.

```
import { ExtraOptions, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

    import {
      NbAuthComponent,
      NbLoginComponent,
      NbLogoutComponent,
      NbRegisterComponent,
      NbRequestPasswordComponent,
      NbResetPasswordComponent,
    } from '@nebular/auth';

import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path : '' , component: LoginComponent},
  { path: 'pages', loadChildren: 'app/pages/pages.module#PagesModule' },
   {
      path: 'auth',
      component: NbAuthComponent,
      children: [
        {
          path: '',
          component: NbLoginComponent,
        },
        {
          path: 'login',
          component: NbLoginComponent,
        },
        {
          path: 'register',
           component: NbRegisterComponent,
        },
        {
          path: 'logout',
          component: NbLogoutComponent,
       },
        {
          path: 'request-password',
         component: NbRequestPasswordComponent,
        },
        {
         path: 'reset-password',
          component: NbResetPasswordComponent,
       },
    ],
  },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'pages' },
];

const config: ExtraOptions = {
  useHash: true,
};

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, config)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To change login component you need to replace `NbLoginComponent` entries in routes array with your custom `LoginComponent`.

Also remove `{path : '' , component: LoginComponent},` and `{ path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },` from routes array.

If you also need to modify common wrapper of auth components (card with back button) you can modify `NbAuthComponent` template.

See [custom auth components guide](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/auth/custom-auth-components#custom-auth-components) for step by step instructions.

Comment: I need to make a custom login page,now i am able to create one inside a auth container.I need to make remove those back button and auth container.Can you help me with that ?